# Find out what word you are hovering mouse over

Tags: pygame

I want to be able to pop up something when the user hovers over particular words that are on a label in pygame.

Can anyone give me a good (or even bad) idea on how to implement this (doesn't have to be pygame specific)? Do I have to put each word in a different label and place them one after the other?

(what I'm calling a label is the result of font.render)

Comment: How are you drawing this label?  With Font.render?

Comment: Yeah sorry, what I'm calling a label is the result of font.render

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `Surface.blit()`, [a rectangle is returned](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.blit) which you can associate with your label.  You could consider keeping a list of these, or a list of tuples of the returned `Rect` and the text or label callback.  In your main loop, you can iterate over this list and call `Rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())` to find out if the mouse is in the current iteration step's `Rect`.

Comment: Thanks! This is much nicer than what I was about to try. Part of the problem is I want to find which words within a sentence are being hovered over, but I will blit them all separately so I know which is which.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to hang on to the surface created by `Font.render()`, you just need the `Rect` that the blit operation returns, so this shouldn't add too much overhead.  Alternatively, you can take a look at [Font.metrics](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#Font.metrics), but I think having to parse the list returned from that would be more work than it was worth.